# Guide on issuing stable coins

Tags: token, issuing

I have seen different guides on how to issue custom tokens on Stellar, but most of them usually lock the issuing account, which would not work for a stable coin as it's supposed to have unlimited supply.

Can anyone help with a guide showing how to issue a stable coin?

Basically, I want to know how to handle the issuing account, how to handle burning the token on redemption and how to automatically detect when any of the stablecoin is sent to a particular address.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to lock your issuing account. The idea of locking the issuing account is to limit the supply of all tokens. Once the issuing account is locked, no more tokens can be ever created again and you have a public proof that this is indeed the case.

For a backed asset you usually want to mint/burn tokens on demand reflecting the supply of the physical asset that is represented by your token. So most likely you are better off with not locking your issuing account.

**Creating new tokens:** Just make a regular payment from the issuing account to any recipient.

**Burning tokens:** Just send the tokens back to the issuing account.

**Tracking payments:** [query a stellar horizon server](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/payments-all.html)